# Using variable which contains $ as password

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to deploy something through Octopus V4 and in my project variables, I got a password in which I have the special character `$`.

Assigning this Octo variable to a PowerShell variable will transform the string because PowerShell surely thinks that there is a variable in it. For instance, if I've got this:

```
azerty$qwerty
```

I'll end up with this:

```
azertyerty
```

So when it comes to start the deployed service with the appropriate credentials, it won't work. Just for the record: before starting the service, I'm creating it with the `New-Service` command in the deployment script of the project.

I read here and there that I need to use single quotes instead of double quotes to make it work but here my hands are tied since I'm just getting the variable from Octopus doing that:

```
$mypassword = $OctopusParameters["password"]
```

Any clue about how to keep the full string, `$` included?

Comment: If PowerShell were expanding the string (which it doesn't, unless you're using something like `Invoke-Expression`, which you shouldn't be using in the first place) you'd end up with just the string `azerty`, because all of `$qwerty` would be expanded to an empty string. Since only `$qw` seems to be expanded I'd suspect it's something Octopus does on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Please see [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) as this may help.

When you enclose a string in single-quotation marks (a single-quoted string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed. When you enclose a string in double quotation marks (a double-quoted string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar sign (`$`) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the command for processing.

See below for an example of this behavior:

```
PS> $for = "my string"

PS> "test$for"
testmy string

PS> 'test$for'
test$for
```

Octopus may have its own way of dealing with this. I would try using double single quotes around the string and see if that helps, like `''my$string''`.

I did also read in a forum that someone had success using the following cmdlet for password:

```
Set-OctopusVariable -Name 'password' -Value 'password123$'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a silly question, but have you tried this already and it didn't work?

If you are using Octopus with the syntax:

```
$mypassword = $OctopusParameters["password"]
```

Octopus will not do any replacement of the value set in the Octopus parameter. Your foreseen issue will only appear if you are setting the password in double quotes inside Powershell directly, as in:

```
$mypassword = "azerty$qwerty"
```

And if you are doing this in Powershell, the correct way to set it will be to escape the $ with the tick (`) as in:

```
$mypassword = "azerty`$qwerty"
```