# To include $ symbol in password variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a password variable in my PowerShell script like below:

```
[string] $username,
[string] $password
```

My password includes $ symbol in it. When I try to call the script by passing password like below.

```
& "script.ps1" -username "admin" -password "Pa$$word"
```

but in the script my password is read like below:

```
password = Paword
```

Is there a way to include $ symbol in my variable? I tried adding '\' symbol before $ but still it is not being read properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question (use single quotes)? [Using variable which contains $ as password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785036/using-variable-which-contains-as-password)

Comment: ... or use a backtick: [PowerShell script not accepting $ (dollar) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1615117/1701026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the password in single quotes as:

```
& "script.ps1" -username "admin" -password 'Pa$$word'
```